# Evenly schedule timed items into fixed size containers

Tags: algorithm

I got a task at work to evenly schedule commercial timed items into pre-defined commercial breaks (containers).

Each campaign has a set of commercials with or without spreading order. I need to allow users to chose multiple campaigns and distribute all the commercials to best fit the breaks within a time window.

```
Example of Campaign A:
Item | Duration | # of times to schedule | order
A1     15 sec          2                    1
A2     25 sec          2                    2
A3     30 sec          2                    3
```

Required outcome:

1. each item should appear only once in a break, no repeating.
2. if there is specific order try to best fit by keeping the order. If
   no order shuffle it.
3. At the end of the process the breaks should contain evenly amount of
   commercial time.
4. Ideal spread would fully fill all desired campaigns into the breaks.

   ```
   For example: Campaign {Item,Duration,#ofTimes,Order}
   Campaign A which has set {A1,15,2,1},{A2,25,2,2},{A3,10,1,3}
   Campaign B which has set {B1,20,2,2},{B2,35,3,1},
   Campaign C which has set {C1,10,1,1},{C2,15,2,3 sec},{C3,15,1,2 sec}
   ,{C4,40,1,4}
   ```

A client will choose to schedule those campaigns in a specific date that hold 5 breaks of 60 second each.

A good outcome would result in:

```
Container 1: {A1,15}{B2,35}{C1,10} total of 60 sec
Container 2: {C3,15}{A2,25}{B1,20} total of 60 sec
Container 3: {A3,10}{C2,15}{B2,35} total of 60 sec
Container 4: {C4,40}{B1,20} total of 60 sec
Container 5: {C2,15}{A3,10}{B3,35} total of 60 sec
```

Of course it's rarely that all will fit so perfectly in real-life examples.

There are so many combinations with large amount of items and I'm not sure how to go about it. The order of items inside a break needs to be dynamically calculated so that the end result would best fit all the items into the breaks.

If the architecture is poor and someone has a better idea (like giving priority to items over order and schedule based on priority or such I'll be glad to hear).

Comment: Sounds like a variation on a [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). You might search Stack Overflow for bin packing. Lots of questions about that, and lots of good answers.

Comment: you are right, it is a variation of bin packing problem although the goal is a bit different. In my case the ultimate goal is to "evenly spread items in containers" whilst in the classic bin packing the goal is to "use minimal number of containers". I want to fill up all my pre-defined containers to the max if possible but if not than have it spread evenly. I should also note that I can run my algorithm multiple times so the containers will be filled completely, so there is no guarantee that the containers are empty nor that they have equal capacity left.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) might be a good way to approach this problem. Just incorporate your constraints of: `keeping order`,  `even spreading` and `fitting into 60sec frame` into the scoring function. Your random neighbor function might just swap 2 items with each other | move an item to a different frame.

Comment: I don't understand how to fulfill it with SA. Can you give an example of pseudo code ?

Comment: I've started writing a simple application of SA to the problem - once it's ready I'll post. The one problem I'm not really addressing (other than a simple linear set of weights) is the scoring function - with so many conditions for a "good" solution, it might be worthwhile to apply fuzzy logic to estimate the score of the solution.